# Dart polymer.dart dart2js

Tags: dart, polymer, dart2js

I made an application with dart / polymer / sockets, and i want to compile it in Javascript. But I don't know how to do. I tried to do "Generate Javascript", but it said "You do not have main entry point".

Should I compile manually each dart files ?

Does build.dart useful ?

**Edit** Added index.html from comments:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="fr"> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" /> 
  <link rel="import" href="console.html" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" /> 
  <script src='packages/polymer/boot.js'></script> 
  <title>XXX</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <fei-console></fei-console> 
  <script type="application/dart"> 
    main() { } 
  </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is complaining about a main entry point, I suspect it cannot find a `main()` function defined anywhere.  In your `index.html` (or whatever the main html file is called), you presumably have a link to a Dart file. Does that file have a `main()` function defined?

Comment: I didn't, I just have a class for my polymer-component. No need for a main() :/

Comment: Actually, I have this in my index.html :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="import" href="console.html" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <script src='packages/polymer/boot.js'></script>
  <title>XXX</title>
</head>
<body>
  <fei-console></fei-console>
  <script type="application/dart"> main() { } </script>
</body>
</html>